# Using normal distribution and CDF to normalize data between 0-1

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization

I need to do the following procedure: 1) first need to transform may data to a normal distribution and 2) to calculate CDF curve to finally get my values distributed between 0-1 range, I mean standardized.

My data represents % of crops area inside a grid cell, so when the cell area and crop are the same my final value is 1 and when there is not any crop my values is 0, so my date is already in the range of 0-1 values, but not normal distributed. When I examine my plots I have too many 0 and 1 values, so this difficult to transform my data into normal.

I tried to remove 0 values and apply for example log(x) function, and then I calculate CDF Curve but the highest values that I get is 0.7975, so my final data range would be between 0.00008-0.7975, but it does not have sense to me because the range it is not 0-1, and it is supposed according to my original highest value, the range must be 1 or near to 1 in my CDF curve, so I can't say that my data is standardized. If I remove 1 values (because I know this the highest truly possible value) the CDF values increase to 0.8560, I think this is better. Any idea or suggestion in this regards, please? Thanks

Comment: Your objective is unclear--what's the point of transforming data to Normality if later you are going to standardize them to the interval $[0,1]$? -- and you haven't supplied any reasons for doing this.  Could you explain?

Comment: Yes of course. I am going to build an ecological index, so I need to put different variables into a normalized scale 0-1, so then I can divide it in ranges acoording the CDF Curve (0-20, 20-40..etc). Some papers that I read do the same, first convert to normal, and then calculate CDF curve, but not gives more details

Comment: That sounds like an inefficient and obscure way to compute (or estimate) the empirical quantile function.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you'd want to do what you are doing. If all you want to do is to transform your data onto (0,1), then why don't you just take the rank and divide by the number of observations + 1?

If your data were already normally distributed, then what you described would achieve something quite similar (up to some randomness, where data will of course randomly never exactly match the quantiles of the distribution function even for relatively large sample sizes):

```
set.seed(1234)
example_data <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=0, sd=1) 
rank(example_data) / (length(example_data)+1)

hist(rank(example_data) / (length(example_data)+1), breaks=50)
hist(pnorm((example_data-mean(example_data))/sd(example_data)), breaks=50)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to follow but if I want to scale my data to [0,1] I divide it by the largest value, which would be 0.7975 in your case.

Comment: The lower limit of this procedure will usually not be $0.$  What do you do when some of the data are negative, for instance?  What do you do when they are mostly negative and the largest is $0$?

Comment: Good point. Might work only with data on an absolute scale - count data, CDF, or, as I (mis?-)understood the example, percentages.

Comment: The question has two requirements, of which the first is to transform the data to look (approximately) Normal. There are no situations, not even with non-negative data, where dividing all results by the maximum will make the data look any more (or less) Normal than they originally do.